# Colorbox html from a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, colorbox

i have a html code

```
<html>
<head>
<script type = "text/javascript" src = "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type = "text/javascript" src = "http://www.jacklmoore.com/colorbox/jquery.colorbox.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://www.jacklmoore.com/colorbox/example1/colorbox.css" />
</head>
    <body>
        <div id="bag">CLICK ME</div>
    </body>
</html>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#bag").click(function(){
    $.colorbox({html:function(){alert("HELLO")}});  
    });
</script>
```

When i click on CLICK ME, alert pop up comes 2 times rather it should come only once. Please tell me

Comment: as far as i see t doesnt work at all.

Answer (score 0):

any way here are some problems with your code:

```
$("#bag").click(function{
$("#bag").click(function(){
```

Comment: yea that was a typing mistake while posting, sry

Comment: @anand you still didnt reply to my comment

Comment: include the colorbox css and js file and jquery 1.9, the above code will open colorbox when you will click on CLICK ME.

Comment: @anand please just give me a fiddle. otherwise im not going to check this out.

Comment: @anand ummm... where can i see the fiddle?

Comment: actually i am building an application where i need to open some content on colorbox. the XHTML content is generated by XSLT transformation and this XHTML is passed in the html attribute of colorbox. In the code, I am generating the content by calling the function on html attribute but this function is being called twice rather it should be called only once